# I want a service like cron job

Tags: php, cron

Main problem is how to create a PHP file automatically and run it on server for some time?
Like when I load abc.php file in my browser it will first create a xyz.php file on server and run it on server side for some specific time and when time completes it will reloads the abc.php file.

Any help please, I want this soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [crontab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)

And in your contab you put something like :

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/file.php
```

And your "file.php" script will be launched every 5 minutes.

Manage your schedules on a database, file.php may run any code you want when a time expires.

Comment: You mean if i run a file abc.php in my browser, this file run  the command like "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/file.php" , then this file.php will run for some time and also it will close after some time or loads agian the abc.php file.?
am i right?

Comment: No, this file.php is executed on the system all the time every 5 minutes even if you didn't launched it on your web browser. But if your file.php reads in a database the actions it has to do, then it could do them.

Comment: Thanks ninso for all the help, but this is the main issue.
Actually i have a chatroom which has random topics that runs for 10 -15 min, then page reloads and new topic will come.
I want a file that runs when i open chatroom and automatically bring topic from db and show topics in chatroom to all users in the world.So i want file.php run when a new chatroom created to bring its topics and close that file.php when chatroom will be closed.
I think i am annoying you, but plz help, this is my issue.

Comment: In such a way, you can use `exec("php /path/to/file.php > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo -n \$!");` on your code, and in file.php you put `sleep(seconds);` and then execute your code. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341421/multi-threading-in-php/12341511#12341511) for details about this command.