# how to call a URL in background using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I want to call a 3rd party URL, this URL is given to me by my SMS portal which is used to send SMS to end users.
Now the problem is that when I call this URL through PHP the state changes and I'm redirected to that page, is there any method by which we can call this URL again and again, the reason I want to call the URL so many times is because there can be 1000 users so in the URL I have to mention the name of the user and there phone number.
This process should be asynchronous.

Comment: will you show ur code atleast

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code here for others to go through it.

Comment: What have you tried, with `PHP` you could call a URL using `file_get_contents()`, `curl`, etc... Maybe try looking at one of those

Answer (score 1):

What about [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) ?

Something like:

```
$code = escapeshellarg("file_get_contents('http://www.site.com/etc...');");
exec("php -r {$code} > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341421/multi-threading-in-php/12341511#12341511) about those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

use CURL .See http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php for more details

Comment: I think Curl will solve the problem...thanks, il try it out and then again get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another script that will send the request and you can then run it from your main script with a shell command by appending `&` or `| at now` at the end of the command to move the process in to background.