# Really daemonize a command when using exec()?

Tags: php, process, exec, parent-child, daemon

From PHP pages of my apache server, I run some commands using a line like :

```
exec("{$command} >> /tmp/test.log 2>&1 & echo -n \$!");
```

You can see an explaination of the arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341421/multi-threading-in-php/12341511#12341511).

But I don't understand something : if I restart or stop my apache server, my command dies too.

```
root@web2:/sx/temp# ps ax | grep 0ff | grep -v grep
15957 ?        S      0:38 /usr/bin/php /sx/site_web_php/fr_FR/app/console task:exec /sx/temp/task_inventaire/ 0ff79bf690dcfdf788fff26c259882e2d07426df 10800
root@web2:/sx/temp#  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting web server: apache2 ... waiting ..
root@web2:/sx/temp# ps ax | grep 0ff | grep -v grep
root@web2:/sx/temp#
```

After some researches, I read some things about parent pids, but using a `&` inside my command-line, I thought I was really detaching my child process from his parent.

I am using apache2 with libapache2-mod-php5 and apache2-mpm-prefork.

**How can I really detach my children programs from apache?**

## edit

You can reproduce it on a Linux/Mac this way :

a) create a executed_script.php file that contains :

```
<?php
sleep(10);
```

b) create a execute_from_http.php file that contains :

```
<?php
exec("php executed_script.php > /tmp/test.log 2>&1 & echo -n \$!");
```

c) run `http://localhost/path/execute_from_http.php`

d) on a terminal, run the command :

```
ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep ; sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ; ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep
```

If you run the command during the 10 secs of the execute_from_http.php script, you'll get the output :

```
php@beast:/var/www/xxx/$ ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep ; sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ; ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep
    1  5257  5245  5245 ?           -1 S       33   0:00 php executed_script.php
 * Restarting web server apache2
 ... waiting    ...done.
php@beast:/var/www/xxx/$
```

As you can see, the `ps` command outputs only once, this tells you that the executed script died when apache restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note, that the '&' in your example is just a boolean AND that concats the *command* and the *echo*. If you want to start the command in *background*, meaning that exec will return immediately, use the `&` at the very end of the command line:

```
exec("{$command} >> /tmp/test.log 2>&1 & echo -n \$! &");
```

---

If you want the process running after apache has finished you'll have to daemonize the process using [`pcntl_fork()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)

Here comes an example:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

switch($pid) {
    case -1 : die ('Error while forking');

    case 0:  // daemon code
         posix_setsid(); // create new process group
         exec("{$command} >> /tmp/test.log 2>&1 & echo -n \$!");
         break;
    default: 
         echo 'daemon started';
         break;

}
```

Now there is no code in the starting PHP scripts that handles the return value of `exec` nor its output. So the current process can finish before `exec` has finished. The worker process will be owned by `init` after this.

---

Also you can have a look at the PEAR package [`System_Daemon`](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon). This can help to daemonize a script.

Comment: No it isn't. The process started via exec still belongs to the apache process group

Comment: I had sames requirements last days and were successful using `pcntl_fork()`. I'm not sure why, but event without explicitely creating a new process group

Comment: This solution doesnt work. I tried to put the `pcntl_fork` inside the apache but (fortunately) it didn't worked. I also tried inside the executed command itself, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: is pcntl_fork enabled? add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` What means `but fortunately it didn't worked` ?

Comment: I say "fortunately" because, when I fork, this creates a second apache2, I can't see what would be the second apache2 behaviour, at the end of the php execution, when the php module ends up. There is no error, but when I kill my apache, I still kill my process.

Comment: Ok. I cannot say yes or no to this at the moment. Note that I've used forking in cli environment last week. But I did such things using apche too ~year ago. Will have to make some tests. Will give you feedback! (But i will AFK for a while, can be tomorrow) The only thing I can say surely at the moment is: We'll find a solution ;)

Comment: :) Thank you, I'm also looking on my way. I come back if I find something.

Comment: Your solution works too if you just add `$sid = posix_setsid();` on the child part of the fork. You also need to create an intermediate executed file that do the fork, so you won't call `pcntl_fork` behind apache.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this news!!! I expected this, but in cli environment it wasn't nessesary. (I don't know why) .I had another idea:  fork and then posix_exec(), this would replace the apache process from memory

Answer (score 2):

## The "at" method

I found a working solution but I don't know if that's ok if we speak performance and security. It uses the `at` command, a kind of cron working only once.

Instead of :

```
exec("php executed_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo -n \$!");
```

Use :

```
exec("echo 'php executed_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1' | at now -M");
```

The key is that `executed_script.php` will be run by an external daemon (atd), so `executed_script.php` will be a child of `atd` and not an apache's one.

```
php@beast:/var/www/xxx$ ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep ; sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ; ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep
 7032  7033   973   973 ?           -1 SN      33   0:00          \_ php executed_script.php
 * Restarting web server apache2
 ... waiting    ...done.
 7032  7033   973   973 ?           -1 SN      33   0:00          \_ php executed_script.php
php@beast:/var/www/xxx$ ps ax | grep 973
 973 ?        Ss     0:00 atd
```

Note several things :

- you can't access the pid of your ran app, if you get `$!` like on my previous pieces of code, you'll get the pid of `at`.
- you need to remove `www-data` which is by default in `/etc/at.deny` (it is probably there with reasons, so take care)
- i have serious doubts about performance : I think that `at` write on a file read by `atd` to communicate

---

## The fork / setsid method

As @hek2mgl wrote in its own answer, we can use a `pcntl_fork()`, but that's not as simple as that. First, you can't run `pcntl_fork()` behind apache, because if we look at the PHP Manual, [Introduction of the Process Control](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php), we can see:

> Process Control should not be enabled within a web server environment
>   and unexpected results may happen if any Process Control functions are
>   used within a web server environment.

When a fork is made, you get two exact copy of the parent process in memory. And because PHP behind apache is run as a module, at the end of the PHP execution (even after a `die()`), you come back to the apache's module wrapper, and you can't control what's going on.

So here is the scenario with an intermediate command that will daemonize your execution:

1) From Apache, you run the intermediate command that will create your daemonized command :

```
$command = escapeshellarg("php executed_script.php");
exec("php run_as_daemon.php {$command} >> /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

2) The intermediate command fork and use `posix_setsid` to **really** detach your command.

```
<?php

if (!isset($argv[1]))
{
    exit;
}
$command = $argv[1];

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid < 0) // error
    exit;
else if ($pid) // parent
    exit;
else // child
{
    $sid = posix_setsid(); // creates a daemon

    if ($sid < 0)
        exit;

    exec("{$command} >> /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

3) Your executed command, of course, doesn't change :

```
<?php
sleep(10);
```

Result :

```
php@beast:/var/www/xxx/$ wget -qO- http://localhost/xxx/execute_from_http.php && sleep 1 && ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep ; sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ; ps axjf | grep execute | grep -v grep
    1 19958 19956 19956 ?           -1 S       33   0:00 php executed_script.php
 * Restarting web server apache2 ......done.
    1 19958 19956 19956 ?           -1 S       33   0:00 php executed_script.php
```